# Is there a way to rotate the legend box in python/seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot, rotation, legend

I'm making velocity according to depth profiles (i'm a geologist) with the depth on the y-axis position. So the first problem I encounter was that for one 'x' (velocity here) I have multiple 'y' (depth) possible. Thus I switch the profile (vel in y-axis and depth in x-axis) and I rotated everything else (labels, ticks..), see picture below and I would just need to rotate of 90° the picture when I'm done. Except the legend box, I've tried many thing without success. I don't know how to rotate it.
Do you have an idea on how to do it ?

Here an example of my code for plot with
d = a dataframe with ["z", "Domains", "x", "vel"]

```
ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
sns.lineplot(data=d, y='vel', x='z', hue="Domains", units='x', estimator=None, lw=1)
plt.ylabel("Velocity (km/s)", labelpad=8.0)
plt.xlabel("Depth below seafloor (km)", rotation=180)
plt.xlim(0,16)
plt.ylim(1,9)
plt.tick_params(direction='out', length=5, width=1, colors='k', labelbottom=True, labeltop=False, labelleft=False, labelright=True, right=True, left=False, grid_color='k', rotation=90)
plt.grid(alpha=0.3, color='k', ls=':')
plt.savefig(Fig_path + 'Comp_domains_tomo2d_ligne.png')
plt.savefig(Fig_path + 'Comp_domains_tomo2d_ligne.ps')
plt.show()
```

[image: 1]

If I don't switch the axis, the z is not constantly increasing as I can have velocity inversion (see the 2nd picture).

[image]

Sorry I can't add portion of my data...

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't matter if each x has multiple y-values in terms of plotting... it will just connect the points in order of appearance you supply so the line will still look the same. You should just plot on the correct axes instead of trying to plot then rotate the image. `x = np.arange(0, 20, np.pi/10); y = np.sin(x); plt.plot(y, x)` has no issue looking normal

Comment: Seems like you just need to switch x and y-axis in your plot, If this is not what you want , provide a minimal reproducible code/data sample

Comment: I'm sorry i must not be clear : it has to follox the z increase but not forcelly the x.  I edited the question and added a picture to show you what is happening if I do it.